# UWP - Programatically bring up the on screen keyboard in ink mode

Tags: c#, keyboard, win-universal-app

For my UWP app (in C#) I'd like to have a button so that when the user presses that Button, the on-screen keyboard would open up **in inking mode** (i.e. where the user can start handwriting and have their handwriting recognized and turned into typed text input).

If I have a textbox and put the focus on the textbox then the on-screen keyboard opens up but in text mode. But what I want is to have it come up in inking mode right from the start, instead of bringing it up in text mode and have the user switch it to ink mode.

Anyone knows how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one of these supported [Components of the Windows Ink platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/ink-walkthrough#components-of-the-windows-ink-platform).

There is also a [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-tutorials-inputs-and-devices/tree/master/GettingStarted-Ink), but keep in mind that a bunch of code is commented.

If you want to tie an event to a push of a button, you can for example switch the focus on that component when the button is pressed.